# Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measurable space. Show that if $E, F \in \mathcal{A}$ and $\mu(E \cap F)=0$, then $\mu(E \cup F)= \mu(E) + \mu(F).$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measurable space. Show that if $E, F \in \mathcal{A}$ and $\mu(E \cap F)=0$, then $\mu(E \cup F)= \mu(E) + \mu(F).$

I can express $E \cup F$ as $$E \cup F= (E \setminus F) \cup (F\setminus E) \cup (E \cap F).$$

Now $$\mu(E \cup F) = \mu ((E \setminus F) \cup (F\setminus E) \cup (E \cap F)) = \mu(E\setminus F) + \mu(F \setminus E)+ 0$$

so $\mu(E \cup F)= \mu(E \setminus F) + \mu(F \setminus E).$ I'm a bit stuck here, is it so that if $E, F$ belong to a $\sigma$-algebra, then $\mu(E \setminus F) = \mu(E)$ and $\mu(F \setminus E) = \mu(F)$? This would seem to make this work.

Comment: $\mu(E)=\mu(E\setminus F)+\mu(E\cap F)$

Comment: Isn't it $\mu(E)=\mu(E\setminus F)+\mu(E\cap F^c)$?

Comment: @UniQGat No. $E\setminus F=E\cap F^c$

Comment: Minor note on terminology. $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ would be a measure space. $(X, \mathcal{A})$ is a measurable space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can complete your argument by noting that
$$\mu(E) = \mu((E \setminus F) \cup (E \cap F)) = \mu(E \setminus F) + \mu(E \cap F) = \mu(E \setminus F),$$
since $E \setminus F$ and $E \cap F$ are disjoint. (And similarly $\mu(F) = \mu(F \setminus E)$)

Answer (score 1):

Note that $E$ is the disjoint union of $E\setminus F$ and $E\cap F$. Thus:

$\mu(E)=\mu(E\setminus F)+\mu(E\cap F)=\mu(E\setminus F)$

And similarly, $\mu(F)=\mu(F\setminus E)$.